# UIScrollView does not scroll offset when voice over is on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uiaccessibility

We have a custom pull to refresh view that is used on on class extending UIScrollViews, everything works fine, however iOS7 disabled the bounce in the ScrollView when VoiceOver is enabled, which renders the pullToRefresh useless.

I am wondering if anyone has been able to see this, and if anyone could give some hints on how to solve this, setting the bounce property to YES when voiceOver is running does not solve it at all.

Update: Tested this issue with existing apps in iOS7 (facebook and gmail), and they all suffer the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you expecting VoiceOver users to use the passthrough gesture and pull to refresh?

Comment: In the ios6,ios5 (the user was getting a post notification to do the pull to refresh, when there was no label letting the user know that he could pull to refresh). And it was possible to pull-to-refresh in the bounce behavior was still present.
However in iOS7 the bounce behaviour is not present when voice over is enabled, rendering the existent pull-to-refresh implementation useless (since it wont scroll to offset<0).

Comment: Interesting. I'm not seeing any indication of pull to refresh in Mail, nor does Mail refocus the list when refresh completes. It does function, however.

Comment: Yes in mail works, and using the UIRefreshControl will also works, which makes this issue stupid on the apple side, as i havent found this documented anywhere.
But if you test it in apps that had a custom pull-to-refresh from those i tested they had it broken also.

This actual makes me think to what will be the actual implementation of UIRefreshControl in tableViews as we could not make the contentOffSet to go <0 when voiceover is on.

Comment: It's best not to assume anything about how accessibility functions within Apple frameworks. You can often mimic behavior, but never implementation. File a Radar if you believe the behavior is wrong.

Comment: Well somehow the UIRefreshControl manages to work (I haven't done proper investigation into this), but i will file a radar, hopefully if I find that this is not an issue the apple guys might be able to give some clues on how to fix this thing.